# Action Script 3. Platform game physics glitch (gravity)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-physics

when my player touches the floor, he is unable to move because he is on the floor and being incremented up.

In the main class I have the movement

```
    private function processMovement():void
    {
        if (touchingGround)
        {   
            if (upKey)
            {
                character.jumpUp();
            }   

            if (leftKey)
            {
                character.moveLeft();
            }

            if (rightKey)
            {
                character.moveRight();
            }

            if (!leftKey && !rightKey && !upKey)
            {
                character.dontMove();
            }

        }
    }
```

Then in the character class you will see this.

```
public class player extends OnGround 
{
    public var canJumpAn:Boolean;
    public var attackAn:Boolean;
    public  var jumpheight:Number = 18;

    public function player() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);

    }

    private function onAdd(e: Event): void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
    }

    public function moveLeft():void 
    {
        //decrease VELOCITY
        xV -= 2;
        if (xV > -7)
        {
            xV = -7;
        }           
        this.gotoAndStop("run");

        //add this to the Mc . x pos baby. 
        this.x += xV;

        this.scaleX = -1;
        charIsrunning = true;
    }


    public function moveRight():void 
    {
        //increase VELOCITY
        xV += 2;
        if (xV > 7)
        {
            xV = 7;
        }
        this.gotoAndStop("run");

        //add this to the Mc . x pos baby. 
        this.x += xV;
        this.scaleX = 1;
        charIsrunning = true;
    }



    public function dontMove():void 
    {
        //if no button presses then do this 
        this.gotoAndStop("stop");

        //slowd down ball 
        xV *= friction;
        charIsrunning = false;
        isDefending = false;

        //stop the ball if you're not moving 
        if (xV > - 1 && xV < 1)
        {
            xV = 0;
        }
    }

    override public function positionOnLand():void
    {
        isJumping = false;
        ///=gotoAndStop(1);

    }

    public function defend():void 
    {
        isDefending = true;
        this.gotoAndStop("defend");
        charIsrunning = false;
    }

    public function attack():void 
    {
        this.gotoAndStop("attack");
    }

    public function jumpUp():void 
    {

        if (!isJumping)
        {
            isJumping = true;
            this.gotoAndStop("jump");
            //
        }

    }




}
```

}

OnGround is another class that player extends, as you can see.

```
public class OnGround extends MovieClip
{
    public var grav:Number;
    public var friction:Number;
    public var xV:Number;
    public var yV:Number;

    protected var charIsrunning:Boolean;
    protected var isDefending:Boolean;
    protected var isJumping:Boolean;

    public function OnGround() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
        charIsrunning = false;
        isDefending = false;
        //gotoAndStsop("jump");
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        //gravity
        grav = 0.6;

        //y velocity 
        yV = 0;

        //x velocity 
        xV = 0;

        //
        friction = 0.9;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fall);

    }

    private function fall(e:Event):void 
    {
        //add grav to y VELOCITY 
        yV += grav;
        trace(yV);


        this.y += yV

    }

    public function incrementUp():void 
    {
        this.y -= 0.1;
        //trace("incrementing");
    }

    public function keepOnGround():void 
    {
        //trace("onGroundBitch");
        grav = 0;   
        yV = 0;
        positionOnLand();
    }

    public function positionOnLand():void 
    {
        //overide
    }

}
```

}

This is a function that's in the main class

```
        for (var c:int = 0; c < childrenOnStage; c++)
        {

            if (getChildAt(c).name == "player")
            {
                if (ground.level1Ground.hitTestPoint(getChildAt(c).x + 13, getChildAt(c).y, true) || ground.level1Ground.hitTestPoint(getChildAt(c).x - 13, getChildAt(c).y, true))
                {
                    getChildAt(c).y --;

                    //OnGround(getChildAt(c)).incrementUp();
                    OnGround(getChildAt(c)).keepOnGround();

                    touchingGround = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    touchingGround = false;
                }
```

The problem is that when the player touches the ground then it's y position is incremented until it isn't touching the ground and then it's suppose to be kept on the ground by turning grav to = 0 and y velocity to 0.

This means gravity is turned off and the players y position will not shift up (when I jump)
or when go down to be kept on ground.

I would appreciate it if someone can lend me a hand or point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Have you tried only setting the speed to zero and leaving the gravity alone? There's really no reason to touch it.

Comment: I've done this, now I have a bigger problem. The increment code should position the players y pos to be on the ground, but then gravity kicks in, pushes it back down and then icrement etc. means shakey screen :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd have a gravity value per object unless you really intend to have different object instances have individual gravities.
If not I'd reference a gravity constant instead.

Is anti-gravity a feature of the game? if not then I'd avoid setting gravity to 0. It may 'work' (to an extent) but it's not a good model/abstraction of reality.

Rather, what I would do is seperate the force applied and the current momentum:
The (downward) force of gravity is applied at all times.
When you're standing on the ground an upward force equal and opposite to gravity is applied.
When you jump, add a one-off instance of upward force.

Use the current forces to change the current momentum and use the current momentum to change the position.

Comment: Right, I will make gravity constant. thus the value not changing.

There is no anti gravity feature. So I will take your advice and make sure no class other than the subclass (which will not change gravity) have access to that variable. 

I don't know what you mean by the third paragraph, forgive me please.

When player hits floor, ( Use the momentum to keep him up Wards)?